# Moving Local Directory All Folder and SubFolders with files to s3 bucket in .Net Core

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

For Example
I have a Folder Name **Cruz** .
Inside Folder I have another two subfolder name as Cruz0 and Cruz1.

Cruz1
a(some format like txt,png)
b(some format like txt,png)
c(some format like txt,png)

Picture (Another Folder)
a(some format like txt,png)
b(some format like txt,png)
Video(Another Folder inside Picture)
ok.png`

Similarly Cruz2 also contains same structure.

Can You Please tell me How to Move same Structure to s3 bucket in .Net code..??

Answer (score 0):

There is no AWS SDK dotnet API to do local folder structure sync to s3. But, you can look at following github code on how to achieve the same with code.

https://github.com/guitarrapc/S3Sync/